# Migrating .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 5.0, AzureFunctions, Cannot convert input parameter 'req' to type 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage'

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, .net-5, .net-core-3.1

I'm in the middle of migrating from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 5.0 for my Azure Functions project. I have the following function decleration:

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;

[Function("Test")]
public static async Task Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage req, 
    ILogger log, 
    Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ExecutionContext context)
{
    ...
}
```

However, I receive the following error message:

```
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.SaveBlob. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
Exception: Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Diagnostics.Exceptions.FunctionInputConverterException: Error converting 1 input parameters for Function 'Test': Cannot convert input parameter 'req' to type 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage' from type 'Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.GrpcHttpRequestData'.
```

I need to keep the ExecutionContext for my application.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading the [Microsoft Documentation about the Execution Context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#execution-context), I see the class was renamed to [FunctionContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.functions.worker.functioncontext?view=azure-dotnet&preserve-view=true)

The fix to the issue was simple, rename `ExecutionContext` to `FunctionContext`. I realize that the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs` is not needed for .NET 5 Azure Functions. Next, I needed to change the type from `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage` to `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http.HttpRequestData`. Lastly, I removed the `ILogger` in favor of the [GetLogger Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.functions.worker.functioncontextloggerextensions.getlogger?view=azure-dotnet&preserve-view=true).

The final function looks like this.

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;

[Function("Test")]
public static HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestData req
        FunctionContext context)
{
    ...
}
```

When upgrading, be sure to thoroughly [read all their documentation about the new changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide). It also helped to create a new project through Visual Studio Code using .NET 5 to see how a new project is structured.